# CSS add border-spacing & border-collapse to thead

Tags: html, css

I have a little spesific question. I'm adding `border-spacing: seperate` to my table. But i want to add `border-spacing` to only thead tag. Is it possible?

Comment: Probably better if you try to explain what kind of layout you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need ```border-bottom``` on my ```th``` tag. But there is need a spacing up there, not on ```td``` at all. But ```border-spacing: separate``` adds to td, too. I just want to delete that spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do (if you want border around your `thead` cells) is to wrap then in a `span` and manipulate it using `css`:

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

table thead th {
  padding: 20px;
}

table thead th span {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span>Month</span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span>Savings</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `border-spacing` only applies to `table` and `inline-table` elements. The value `separate` (not `seperate`) is not a valid value for the `border-spacing` property, but is used on the `border-collapse` property instead.

Comment: Yes, i added border-bottom to your code and it doesn't work actually. Just, thead makes text centered that's why you thought it works.

Comment: Maybe padding would work, but i have borders. I need real spacings :)

Comment: @EmirhanEngin Well so please specify it in your question ;)

Comment: How can i fix this? I tried all of solutions but doesn't work:(

Comment: @EmirhanEngin Is it now a solution for you ?

Comment: Yaaay! Thank you so much :) It's about experience, isn't it? :)) I'm really appreciate it :)

Comment: @EmirhanEngin Hehe I think ;) Can you please `upvote` all usefull answers thanks :)

Comment: To be honest, i can't :( i need 15 reputation point but i have only 13... When i have 15 reputation point, i will upvote:)